# Revise.jl not reloading project in jupyter

Tags: julia, jupyter

I am using the following cell code in jupyter notebook:

```
using Revise
includet("../../src/MyProject.jl")
using .MyProject
```

However, if I make edits to the project source and rerun the cell the updates are not applied.  I have to restart the entire kernel for it to reload.

How can I make reloading work?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the issue or if it helps, but the more "normal" workflow would be to add your `MyProject` to the environment that your using (the package manager can also deal with relative paths). In these cases Revise always works for me. I never tried a case like yours.